# Materialize Hover button doesn't work with React Router

Tags: reactjs, materialize, react-router-dom

The problem: a Materialize CSS floating button works perfectly, but when I change page (with react  router dom) for example HOME > ABOUT > HOME again it doesn't anymore.

Home:

```
import AddBtn from "../layout/AddBtn-float";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <SearchBar />
      <div className="container">
        <AddBtn />
...
```

AddBtn.js

```
const AddBtn = () => {
  return (
    <div className="fixed-action-btn direction-top">
<a
        href="#add-task-modal"
        className="btn-floating btn-large blue darken-2 modal-trigger"
      >
        <i className="large material-icons">add</i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a
            href="#user-list-modal"
            className="btn-floating green modal-trigger"
          >
            <i className="material-icons">person</i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#add-user-modal" className="btn-floating red modal-trigger">
            <i className="material-icons">person_add</i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddBtn;
```

I'm not an expert but looks like a Materialize "bug" that needs a workaround.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I write the solution may someone needs it.
Just put in every page

```
useEffect(() => {
    M.AutoInit();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
```

I used it just in App.js but looks not enough